# signalr android (kotlin) cannot connect to server because it is always DISCONNECTED

Tags: android, kotlin, asp.net-core

I use implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:6.0.8' for android (kotlin) and backend is .Net 6
but the emulator cannot connect to the server (localhost). I try to code a function to check hubConnection.connectionState, it is DISCONNECTED.
no error happened. Can anyone guide me to find the error, here is the code:

```
import com.microsoft.signalr.Action1
import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection
import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnectionBuilder
import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnectionState
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory


class SignalRListener private constructor(){
    private var hubConnection: HubConnection
    private var logger: Logger

    init {
        logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HubConnection::class.java)
        // define in constructor
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://10.0.2.2:5291/hubs/presence")
            .withAccessTokenProvider(Single.defer { Single.just("${Constanst.TOKEN}") })
            .build()

        hubConnection.on("UserIsOnline",
            Action1 { member: Member -> println(member.DisplayName + "online") },
            Member::class.java
        )

        hubConnection.on("UserIsOffline",
            Action1 { username: String -> println(username+" offline") },
            String::class.java
        )

        hubConnection.on(
            "GetOnlineUsers",
            Action1 { usersOnline : List<Member> ->
                for (item in usersOnline) {
                    println(item.DisplayName)
                }
            },
            List::class.java
        )
        hubConnection.start().doOnError({ logger.info("Client connected error.") })
    }

    private object Holder { val INSTANCE = SignalRListener() }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(): SignalRListener{
            return Holder.INSTANCE
        }
    }

    fun stopHubConnection(){
        if(hubConnection.connectionState == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED){
            hubConnection.stop()
        }
    }

    fun getConnectionState(){
        println(hubConnection.connectionState.toString())
    }

    fun log(){
        logger.info("Debug infor siganlR {}", hubConnection.connectionId)
    }
}
```

Web (React) runs well with the backend.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var signalR: SignalRListener;
    var btnCheck: Button? = null
    var btnLog: Button? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        signalR = SignalRListener.getInstance()

        btnCheck = findViewById(R.id.btnCheck)
        btnCheck?.setOnClickListener {
            signalR.getConnectionState()
        }

        btnLog = findViewById(R.id.btnLog)
        btnLog?.setOnClickListener {
            signalR.log()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use emulator android run server at localhost. but when starting the hub at the client, there is no connection to the app server

Comment: let me check this your advice

Comment: @MansoorMalik WIFI in my emulator is connecting. but I don't understand why it can't connect to the app server (Net 6).
I have used SignalR client for Flutter, Angular, React, Winform (C#) all works fine with .Net 6

Answer (score 0):

As you are in the android emulator, You have to access your localhost so that it reaches your server. If you need internet through proxy you can also set it from the Settings and Proxy and there you can define your proxy settings.

[image]

Comment: I use this library (com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:6.0.8) for kotlin is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is from Microsoft, No issues with that.

Comment: but I don't understand why it can't connect to the app server (Net 6). I have used SignalR client for Flutter, Angular, React, Winform (C#) all works fine with .Net 6

Comment: Do we have a SignalR lib version specifically for Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the following:
in BE(.Net Core) remove this line:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

and the client calls http not https:

```
hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://10.0.2.2:5291/hubs/presence")
hubConnection.start().blockingAwait()
```

It worked fine